# Index out of range for the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

'''

```
marksheet=[]
scorelist=[]
for i in range(0,int(input())):
    name=input()
    score=float(input())
    marksheet.append([name,score])
    scorelist.append(score)
second_marks=sorted(list(dict.fromkeys(score_list)))[1]# @here code is reflecing error that it list index is out of range.
```

for name,marks in sorted(mark_sheet):
        if marks == second_lowest_mark:
            print(name)

'''

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense--please fix the indentation and describe what you're giving to `input` (better yet, just hardcode in failing data). `score_list` is undefined. Please provide a [mcve]. What is the expected output? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: marksheet and scorelist are the empty list and user will enter any no. and based on that no, user will enter that no of times name and score.

Answer (score 0):

The error here is NameError: name 'score_list' is not defined. Change it and see.

```
marksheet=[]
scorelist=[]
for i in range(0,int(input())):
    name=input()
    score=float(input())
    marksheet.append([name,score])
    scorelist.append(score)
second_marks=sorted(list(dict.fromkeys(scorelist)))[1]
```

I think this is the problem you have. unless what is your expected output?